# No credentials needed for Sqlite database?

Tags: android, angularjs, database, sqlite, ionic-framework

I am not quite getting the idea of `sqlite` database. I am developing a hybrid mobile app using `Ionic` Framework and backend with `PHP`.

I referrred to this article for using the sqlite https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/11/use-sqlite-instead-local-storage-ionic-framework/

I have a few questions now,

**1)** So, anybody can create a table,insert and do any kind of operations? Is'nt there any need of a security method to access the `DB` like `mysql`?

**2)** Is a separate instance of Sqlite created for each application? Coz if not,I can make a guess for a `tablename` created by any other application and delete it all together,isn't it? I just dont get it?

Comment: `Is a separate instance of Sqlite created for each application?` yes.

Comment: Okay, so none of the other apps will even come to know about my db,rite? Can you explain me in more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) SQLite is a file database so if you have access to file you have access to database and can do anything with it. What is the purpose of restricting access to db when you can just delete whole file? SQLite db file should be created in app private storage so no one have access to it only your app.

2) the answear is above. just create file in right place and everything will be fine :)

Comment: Creating the file in the right place make the db to be available only for your application on regular devices. If you are afraid of stealing info from your db you have to encrypt the data . On emulator s very easy to get to /data/data/<package>/ so the file can be stolen. of course on cyanogen devices too.

Comment: I agree. It works without root. If you have root acces (emulator cyanogen mode or rooted device) you can do anything in your system so stealing file is pretty obvious. I think if you need to store sensitive data do it outside of the device.

Comment: I am sorry, but what  you exactly mean by outside of the device? I am using a cordova plugin of sqlite

Comment: outside of the device mean external dedicated server with for example MySQL and REST service :) but you need internet connection to communicate.

Comment: but that would defeat the purpose of local storage..isn't it? may be encoding the database is the only option?

Comment: encrypting rather. fast googling https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
1) So, anybody can create a table,insert and do any kind of operations? Is'nt there any need of a security method to access the DB like mysql?
```

By default, each app db will store in their private folder(`data/data/your_package_name/database` and only that app or system app can access to it.
But if you choose to store your db in sdcard, anybody can mess up your db if they know the path to db file and have right to access it.
Other case is if your device is root, other apps can access your db too.

```
2) Is a separate instance of Sqlite created for each application? Coz if not,I can make a guess for a tablename created by any other application and delete it all together,isn't it? I just dont get it?
```

Like above, each app can choose where to store their db file, so basically, they a separate instance.
 
You can also create multi db file for one app if you like.